# Digital clock Typeface with same width

Tags: font

I am seeking for a digital clock typeface in which the characters (I just need the digits) have the same width. I'll be using it for a countdown so if the digits don't have the same width the **countdown I am building will be changing its width every 1000/60 milliseconds** (**NOT A GOOD USER EXPERIENCE**) and that's exactly what I am willing to avoid.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: are you looking for something like this?  http://codepen.io/maneeshc/full/mJBYqy/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a lazy question solved with a simple Google search

Comment: It's easy to Google for a suitable font if you know the term to search for. I've posted an answer that helps with the terminology. :)

Comment: This is a font request, not a User Experience problem being solving. Therefore it's not suited to this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Fixed-width fonts

You need what's called [a monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), or a fixed-width, font.

Wikipedia has a sample page of monospaced fonts, to get you started. On this page, you'll see a wide range of aesthetic choices. You can choose something that conveys the feeling you want, for your clock and your context.

[image][image][image]